# Interiors and Closures of Various sets in different topologies.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification

Find the interiors and closures of the following sets in the given spaces:

(a) (0, 1] in $\Bbb{R_{usual}}$. Closure: [0,1], int = (0,1)

(b) (0, 1] in the Sorgenfrey Line. Closure: [0,1], int = (0,1]

(c) (0, 1] in $(\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{indiscrete}})$. Closure = $\Bbb{R}$, int = $\emptyset$

(d) (0, 1] in $(\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{discrete}})$. Closure = (0,1], int = (0,1]

(e) (0, 1] in $(\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{ray}})$. Closure = [0,1], int = $\emptyset$

(f) (0, 1] in $(\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{co-finite}})$. Closure = [0,1], int = $\emptyset$

(g) The set E of even numbers in $(\Bbb{Z}, \mathcal{T_{co-finite}})$. Closure = $\Bbb{Z}$, int = $\emptyset$

(h) $\Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R_{usual}}$. Closure= $\Bbb{R}$, int = $\emptyset$

(i) $\Bbb{Q}$ in the Sorgenfrey Line. Closure = $\Bbb{R}$, int = $\emptyset$

(j) $\Bbb{Q} × \Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R^2_{ususal}}$ Closure = $\Bbb{R^2}$, int = $\emptyset$

(k) $\{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb{R^3} : x = 0 \}$ in $\Bbb{R}^3_{usual}$. Not sure

Can I please get some feedback/corrections on my solution

Comment: What is $\mathcal T_{\textit ray}$?

Comment: Also, at a glance, your answers to (b) interior, (f) closure seem to be wrong. For (k), just think about an analogous thing in two dimensions.

Comment: @tomasz:Should (b) interior = [0,1) because $\bigcup [\frac{1}{n}, 1)$ = (0, 1) and should (f) closure = all infinite subsets for (k) closure = $\Bbb{R} \times {y,x}$ ?

Comment: Also $\mathcal{T_ray}$ = all sets of the form $(a, \infty) : a \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: In (k) the set is closed and has empty interior. And  tomasz is correct about (b) and (k). And the closure in (e) is wrong.

Comment: @user254665 should the closure for e be $(-\infty,1]$ , since any x <= 0, will be contained in an open set of the form $(x-t, \infty)$ in particular it will contain (0, 1] ? Also are my answers to b and f in the comments above correct ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct for (e).... For (b),  for the Int:  Note that $ 0\not \in (0,1]$ so $0\not \in Int (0,1], $  and  with regard to the attempt in your Q, no nbhd of $1$ is a subset of $(0,1]$..... For (f) for Closure, any co-finite subset intersects $(0,1].$  In the co-finite  topology on any set $X,$  any infinite subset of $X$ is dense in $X.$